# How to calculate the sum of row values (tenure calculation)

Tags: r

This is part of my dataset:

```
ID  year  mrg_status 
 1  1990           2
 1  1991           1
 1  1992           1
 1  1993           4
 2  1990           2
 2  1991           2
 2  1992           1
 3  1991           2
 3  1992           1
 3  1995           1
 ...
```

In `mrg_status`, 2 means "single" 1 means "married" and 4 means "divorced". What I want to do is to calculate marriage_tenure for each ID and add the fourth column to record it. The result should look like this:

```
ID  year  mrg_status mrg_tenure
 1  1990           2          0
 1  1991           1          1
 1  1992           1          2
 1  1993           4          2
 2  1990           2          0
 2  1991           2          0
 2  1992           1          1
 3  1991           2          0
 3  1992           1          1
 3  1995           1          4
```

I have tried:

```
 if(dt$mrg_status ==1){dt$mrg_tenure = sum(dt$mrg_status,by="ID"}
```

but this seems to be totally a mess. And an important problem is how to deal with the `mrg_status` = 4, it has the same `mrg_tenure` as the previous year where `mrg_status` = 1. I am thinking about writing a loop where it can detect "4" and stop adding up `mrg_tenure`.

Comment: It is not clear how you got the output

Comment: @akrun as per my understanding, it is the difference between the current year when the person is married and the year when person was single.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here is what I did

```
df <- data.frame(
    ID = c(1, 1, 1, 1, 2, 2, 2, 3, 3, 3),
    year= c(1990, 1991, 1992, 1993, 1990, 1991, 1992, 1991, 1992, 1995),
    mrg_status = c(2, 1, 1, 4, 2, 2, 1, 2, 1, 1)
)

mrg_tenure <- sapply(
    X = split(df, df$ID), FUN = function(df1){
        ifelse(
            test = (df1$mrg_status == 2),
            yes = 0,
            no = ifelse(
                test = (df1$mrg_status == 1),
                yes = df1$year - max(df1[df1$mrg_status == 2, c('year')]),
                no = max(df1[df1$mrg_status == 1, c('year')]) - max(df1[df1$mrg_status == 2, c('year')])
            )
        )
    }
)

df$mrg_tenure <- do.call(c, mrg_tenure)

# ID year mrg_status mrg_tenure
# 1   1 1990          2          0
# 2   1 1991          1          1
# 3   1 1992          1          2
# 4   1 1993          4          2
# 5   2 1990          2          0
# 6   2 1991          2          0
# 7   2 1992          1          1
# 8   3 1991          2          0
# 9   3 1992          1          1
# 10  3 1995          1          4
```

- Split By ID
- For each ID if status == 2, set tenure = 0
- If status == 1 then subtract current year with the year when person was single
- Else status == 4, hence person is divorced, set tenure with the last tenure when person was married

Comment: And I tried running the code with the "dt" as you defined, another error shows up: ` Error in do.call(c, mrg_tenure) : 
  'what' must be a character string or a function`

Comment: it is `df` . Just copy paste the code.. It runs without error for me.

Comment: Yeah..That's what I did. I copied and pasted but still shows "Error in do.call(c, mrg_tenure) : 
  'what' must be a character string or a function" . I will try again tomorrow after cleaning the workspace

Comment: BTW, can I know what version of R you are using?

Comment: try this `do.call("c", mrg_tenure)` Where `c` is quoted